# Solaris 9 : memory leak detection

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, solaris

We're trying to detect a memory-leak scenario at a customer site. We're using JNI to call into C code which in turns uses a 3rd party library (open source).

I understand that memory leaks happen on account of one of these : java code, JRE, JNI related code and the 3rd party code.

How should I go about detecting the leaks ? What tools ? Procedures ?

We've been told to look at libumem and actively considering using it.

Thank you,

**UPDATE**
the Java app calls down to C code using JNI.
Metrics for java code : no.
3rd party library : NetSNMP.
Java Heap looks more or less constant So, we're looking more towards JNI or 3rd party C libraries.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about your setup?  For example, if the JNI calls into 3rd party C code are all short lived, that implies that neither the JNI nor that C 3rd party libraries are at fault, and you have a memory leak in your Java application itself.  What are your memory metrics within your Java application telling you?  You have metrics...right?  What have periodic heap dumps of your Java application revealed?

Answer (score 4):

[Memory Leak Detection with libumem](http://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/memory_leak_detection_with_libumem)

[Finding Memory leaks Within Solaris Applications using umem](http://blogs.oracle.com/pnayak/entry/finding_memory_leaks_within_solaris)